# How to design form inheritance

Tags: forms

I need to design about 20 forms for various business processes.
We have to do this for about 10 countries and need some form of object prietnted approach because each country has different business rules and some different bits of data. However, there is also common data between some of these countries.

For example, we have 5 bits of data, 4 are common to every country, 1 is specific for individual countries.
 eg common Name, Address, Telephone, Male/Female
 eg Bonus payment

It's a question of how do you manage all the code changes easily in an enterprise application without the code being too unwieldy?

It's not just the languages, that would essentially be driven by a config code that lists the names for the lables...but also each form may have most of it's design from a gloabl form and then less from a local form, local to the specific country.

Isn't there some way to build a dynamic form on the fly so that you have 1 form ProcessBonus for every country, that form inherits fields from MainForm, and then it checks configuration Class in the background to build the form dynamicaly for each country?

I'm trying to avoid having 10 form types and then another 100 local forms for each country, that would be well over 1000 forms and would be unmanageable wouldn't it?

Comment: Make use of Interfaces !

Comment: Can you do that in .NET or is that Java only?

Comment: Possible with .net too.

Comment: what is it called in .NET?

Answer (score 0):

Actually what you need to achieve is Multiple Inheritance. .Net technologies , PHP, FLEX etc some other languages doesn't support multiple inheritance. Thus, *Interfaces* are used as a hack to achieve multiple inheritance.

You can find the implementation of interfaces in this link.

http://www.codersource.net/MicrosoftNet/CBasicsTutorials/CNetTutorialInterfaces.aspx

Comment: Thanks. That site says "The interface can't contain constants, data fields, constructors, destructors and static members."
The problem I have is that each form will have a different label name depending on the country and the above says data fields cannot be used. So, should the data field config be taken from a JSON file?

Comment: Each country may also have different validation criteria so each country should have its own class with different code?

Comment: Yea true. Interfaces can't contain access modifiers, but they can contain method signatures.

Comment: @second comment, yep exactly.  The classes that inherit the interfaces must define the methods.

Comment: So eg the class inherits Mainform but then it can have methods that state what to do with data and fields?

Comment: I would assume that dealing with objects that generate these forms. These objects would consist of other objects that make up the sections of the form. Those section objects could be virtual, or the final form could be the one that's doing the inheriting